# Install English TeamViewer 9 on Chinese Windows

Tags: windows-xp, installation, vpn, language, teamviewer

I need to install English language TeamViewer on a computer in China running Chinese Windows XP.

I don't own the computer so can't change the OS. It's in a hotel with a computer but without Wi-Fi. But I've found I am able to install software (I don't know if it will get erased on reboot).

I use TeamViewer to VPN my way past the Great Firewall of China.

Now TeamViewer's download page does let me choose a langauge and I do choose English, but when the installer runs it's in Chinese.

If I just fumble through the installer it's not installed in the same way as on my laptop and won't allow my to connect to the remote machine I use. Of course I cannot read any of the error messages either.

I looked at forcing the installer to run in English, but it's not a `.msi` but a `.exe`

**How can I force Team Viewer to install a version with English User interface or change the settings of the interfeace from Chinese to English once it's installed?**

Comment: Would the downvoter like to provide some constructive feedback about the problem with the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the language, goto :

- Click `Extras`
- Then `Options`
- Then `Advanced`
- Then `Show advanced options`
- Here you can select your Language using the dropdown list `display language`
- Restart Teamviewer

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hopefully they're in the same order in Chinese! Let me see ...

Comment: I get as far as selecting "English" from the dropdown. Then the dialog as two buttons, "K" is the hotkey for the left one, and "C" for the right. No matter which I click on I then see the user interface still in Chinese. Perhaps I also need the next step, even if it might seem obvious?

Comment: Try both :) the `OK` button should be the one on the left. You have to close and restart Teamviewer for changes to take effect

Comment: Oh yes, the left one is "确定(K)" which translates to "OK". After restarting it's now in English. You get a cookie! (-: